# MIXED DML Exception Custom settings + UserPackageLicense

Tags: mixed-dml

I am trying to update a Custom Setting record and insert an UserPackageLicense record in the same transaction, however I am facing MIXED DML exception.

Why do I face this exception? I thought custom settings where setup objects, as well as UserPackageLicense. I understand I cannot mix setups and non-setup object DMLs but I would say this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

A Custom setting is not a Setup object. Setup objects are, conceptually, objects that aid with the setup of the org itself (think User, Profile, Group, etc).  The `CustomSetting` object itself is probably a setup object (I am not 100% sure there) but data inside a specific custom setting is most definitely not considered setup.

The list of Setup Objects can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/reference_objects_setup.htm), though I admit this link feels incomplete

Comment: I see... that links does not shows UserPackageLicense because it is incomplete...?

Comment: And why are custom settings then throwing MIXED DML exceptions in test classes?

In here, it says that "You can’t use custom settings in Apex code saved using Salesforce API version 17.0 and earlier with other sObjects when performing DML operations in the same transaction." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_non_mix_sobjects.htm

Comment: You have not pasted any code, so I cannot answer your question more than I have. However, is your Apex pre-API v.17?  That article says that pre 17.0, CS were considered "Setup". After, they are not. You may have read that in reverse